# Where to set devtools = true for vue.js devtools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

The main.js of my vue app looks like this:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './style/customColor.scss';

import store from "./store/store";
import { USER_ROLECHECK } from './store/actions/user'
import { REQ_ADMIN_ROLE } from "./utility/namespaces";

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.reqAuth){
    if(store.getters.isAuthenticated){
      if(to.meta.reqAdmin){
        store.dispatch(USER_ROLECHECK, REQ_ADMIN_ROLE).then(() =>{
          next();
        }).catch(() =>{
          next({path: '/'})
        })
      }else{
        next();
      }
    }else{
      next({path: '/login'});
    }
  }else{
    next();
  } 
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

Im running vue in production mode. I still want to use devtools, but they give me this error:

```
Vue.js is detected on this page.
Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.
```

I read here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/190 that I need to change main.js like this:

```
You are probably using Vue from CDN, and probably using a production build (dist/vue.min.js). Either replace it with a dev build (dist/vue.js) or add Vue.config.devtools = true to the main js file.
```

But I dont know where to make this entry into my projects/apps main.js :(
Please help!

Comment: Did you tried to add `Vue.config.devtools = true` just before `new Vue({....})` ? It should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer myself:
This is what the code of main.js looks like with devtools=true:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './style/customColor.scss';

import store from "./store/store";
import { USER_ROLECHECK } from './store/actions/user'
import { REQ_ADMIN_ROLE } from "./utility/namespaces";

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
//HERE IT IS=============================================================
Vue.config.devtools = true; //this line should be removed in the actual live 
build!
//HERE IT IS==================================================

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.reqAuth){
    if(store.getters.isAuthenticated){
      if(to.meta.reqAdmin){
        store.dispatch(USER_ROLECHECK, REQ_ADMIN_ROLE).then(() =>{
          next();
        }).catch(() =>{
          next({path: '/'})
        })
      }else{
        next();
      }
    }else{
      next({path: '/login'});
    }
  }else{
    next();
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```